# Actionscript 3 Socket.readInt() and c# Socket.Send() different values of int-variable

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, sockets

When I send number (int)52 `s.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)872415232));`, flash show me `trace(socket.readInt());` 872415232
If i send 872415232, flash show 52... Why? And how it fix?

Answer (score 3):

It's an [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (byte order) issue.

If you convert the numbers into hexadecimal things become more clear:

```
 872415232 = 0x34000000
        52 = 0x00000034
```

- For Actionscript's `Socket`: "The default value is Endian.BIG_ENDIAN."
- For C#'s `BitConverter`: "The order of bytes in the array returned by the GetBytes method overloads [...] depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian." (Little endian in your case).

You need to decide whether you want to use little endian or big endian and then change the Actionscript and C# code to always use this endianness.

- Actionscript: You can change the [`endian`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html#endian) property of the `Socket`.
- C#: You can use the `MiscUtil.Conversion.EndianBitConverter` from Jon Skeet's [MiscUtil library](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/).

If you don't want to include a whole new library just to choose the endianness in C# you can just write a short method instead:

```
int SwapEndianness(int x)
{
    return (x >> 24) +
           ((x >> 8) & 0x0000ff00) +
           ((x << 8) & 0x00ff0000) + 
           (x << 24);
}
```

Comment: Thx you.. Could you help me with the c# code for change endian?

Comment: Simply swapping endiness in C# might not be the best idea, unless you are 100% sure you are currently in the wrong endianness. Eg, you might need a way to detect system endianess.

Comment: @Jonaton: the bitconverter class has a readonly property that tells you the endianness. You should check that first.